Is there a shortcut in Pycharm for generating HTML boilerplate?
I understand that most good HTML code editors have a way to generate HTML boilerplate, but does Pycharm have this functionality, ideally through a shortcut?
I tried searching for the shortcuts menu on PyCharm, but couldn't find it

PyCharm has a functionality to generate HTML boilerplate-
Type html:5 and then press Tab or Enter
This is abbreviation to a complete HTML5 boilerplate

You can try below steps to use live templates, you can quickly generate HTML boilerplate code in PyCharm, improving your productivity.

Open Settings/Preferences:


Go to File > Settings (or PyCharm > Preferences on macOS).


Navigate to Live Templates:


Expand the Editor section.
Select Live Templates.


Add or Modify a Template:


You can add a new template by clicking the + button.

Select Template Group and name your group (e.g., HTML).

Within that group, click the + button again and select Live Template.

Define your abbreviation (e.g., html5), description, and the template text.

Set the context to HTML so that this template is only available in HTML files.


Hope this help

Access Settings/Preferences:

On Windows/Linux: Go to File > Settings.
On macOS: Go to PyCharm > Preferences.
Navigate to Live Templates:

Expand the Editor section.
Select Live Templates.


